# Debug Web App on Default Android Browsers (Not Chrome)

Tags: android, debugging, web-applications, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging

I am investigating how to debug web applications on Android Browsers. I have done some investigation and understand that starting from Android 4.4, the **default** Android browsers are based on Chromium, so using Chrome for Android to debug Android 4.4+ should be close enough.

My questions is mainly regarding default Android browsers on Jelly Bean (Android 4.1-4.3) devices.

1. Is Chrome for Android close enough to most of the default Android
   browsers?
2. For default browsers that are not Chrome, what is the best
   way to debug?

For question #2, I have seen many people recommending [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/). Is weinre the best option available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, old Android browser is nothing like the new, Chromium-based, one. Different features, different performance, different quirks.

You have couple of options to debug browsers on Android < 4.4:

- [jshybugger.com](https://www.jshybugger.com/#!/) - probably the best one, but commercial
- [weinre](https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/) - last time I checked it was randomly dropping connection and was quite complicated to get running in the first place, but it's the best free option out there
- [firebug lite](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) - if you are desperate you can add firebug lite to your website and try using it on your phone. Super awkward, but better than nothing.
- `console.log` - if you'll use a WebView you'll get output from `console.*` calls in Android Studio

Comment: Thanks! Listing the options in order helps a lot and it's also good to know old android browsers are different